# Angle between lines whose direction cosines are related by given equations

Tags: geometry

Find the angle between the lines whose direction cosines $l$, $m$ & $n$ are linked by the following two equations.

$$l+m+n=0$$
$$mn/(q-r)+nl/(r-p)+lm/(p-q)=0$$

Where $p$, $q$ and $r$ are constants.

Answer given is $\pi/3$

I have been trying to solve this for past hour. I have tried eliminating n from both equations and converting the second equation into a quadratic equation with variable l/m. Now the two roots of this equation will be the ratio of direction cosines of both the lines. I am unable to proceed further from there.

Formula for angle is as follows:
Cos ($\theta$) = $l_1l_2+m_1m_2+n_1n_2$
 where $l_1,m_1,n_1$ are direction cosines of first line and $l_2,m_2,n_2$ are direction cosines of second line

Comment: Use $l^2+m^2+n^2=1$.

Comment: Are $(p,q,r)$ the direction cosines of the second line??

Comment: I have tried to use thus identity but I am unable to get the solution.

Comment: p, q and r are constants.

Comment: OK. There are two lines. What symbols denote the direction cosines of the second one?

Comment: When we solve these two equations, we will get a pair of direction cosines. I want the angle between those two Direction cosines

Comment: It seems to me that you don't understand direction cosines. The direction cosines of a line are three numbers. So, $(l,m,n)$ for the first line, and (I suspect) $(p,q,r)$ for the second line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87274/discussion-between-sai-teja-and-bubba).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that $l,m,n\ne0$. This is because, say, if $l=0$, we will have $m+n=0,mn=0\therefore l^2+m^2+n^2=0\ne1$.

Now, the angle between the vectors whose direction cosines $(l_1,m_1,n_1),(l_2,m_2,n_2)$ are given by the equations is equal to the angle between the vectors $(1,m_1/l_1,n_1/l_1)\equiv(1,x_1,y_1),(1,m_2/l_2,n_2/l_2)\equiv(1,x_2,y_2)$, provided $l_1l_2>0$.

$$\displaystyle\cos\theta=\frac{l_1l_2+m_1m_2+n_1n_2}{\sqrt{l_1^2+m_1^2+n_1^2}\sqrt{l_1^2+m_1^2+n_1^2}}=\frac{l_1l_2}{|l_1l_2|}\cdot\frac{1+x_1x_2+y_1y_2}{\sqrt{1+x_1^2+y_1^2}\sqrt{1+x_2^2+y_2^2}}$$

Divide $l+m+n=0$ by $l$,$$1+x+y=0$$

Instead of juggling $3$ constants $p,q,r$, take $q-r=A,r-p=B$ and divide $\displaystyle\frac{mn}A+\frac{nl}B-\frac{lm}{A+B}=0$ by $l^2$,$$\displaystyle\frac{xy}A+\frac yB-\frac x{A+B}=0$$

Eliminate $y$ to get,

$$\displaystyle\frac{x^2}A+x\Big(\frac1A+\frac1B+\frac1{A+B}\Big)+\frac1B=0$$

Sum of roots,$$\displaystyle x_1+x_2=-A\Big[\frac1B+\frac1{A+B}\Big]-1$$

Product of roots,$$\displaystyle x_1x_2=\frac AB$$

$\displaystyle1+x_1x_2+y_1y_2=1+x_1x_2+(1+x_1)(1+x_2)=2+x_1+x_2+2x_1x_2=\frac{A^2+AB+B^2}{B(A+B)}$

$(1+x_1^2+y_1^2)(1+x_2^2+y_2^2)\\=(1+x_1^2+(1+x_1)^2)(1+x_2^2+(1+x_2)^2)\\=4(x_1^2+x_1+1)(x_2^2+x_2+1)$

Substitute for $x_1^2,x_2^2$ from the quadratic equation,

$=4\Big[1-\frac AB-Ax_1\Big(\frac1B+\frac1{A+B}\Big)\Big]\Big[1-\frac AB-Ax_2\Big(\frac1B+\frac1{A+B}\Big)\Big]\\=4\Big[\Big(1-\frac AB\Big)^2-A\Big(1-\frac AB\Big)\Big(\frac1B+\frac1{A+B}\Big)[x_1+x_2]+A^2\Big(\frac1B+\frac1{A+B}\Big)^2x_1x_2\Big]\\=\frac4{B^2(A+B)^2}\Big[(B-A)^2(B+A)^2+\frac AB(B-A)(A+2B)(A^2+3AB+B^2)+\frac{A^3}B(A+2B)^2\Big]$

We have $3$ terms in the sums. I simplified the last $2$ terms first because they have more in common.

$\displaystyle=\frac{4[A^2+B^2+AB]^2}{B^2(A+B)^2}$

We get $\displaystyle\cos\theta=\frac{1+x_1x_2+y_1y_2}{\sqrt{1+x_1^2+y_1^2}\sqrt{1+x_2^2+y_2^2}}=\pm1/2\therefore\theta=\pi/3,2\pi/3$.

In any case, since we are talking about **lines** which extend in both directions indefinitely and not vectors, the angle between them is often stated as the acute angle between them, given by $\pi/3$.

Comment: Well done. (+1). I hope the OP appreciates all this effort.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the answer Shubham. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

A clarification of the question, and some steps towards a solution:

Suppose the direction cosines of the two lines are $(l_1,m_1,n_1)$ and $(l_2,m_2,n_2)$. We are told (I think) that

\begin{aligned}
 &l_1 + m_1 + n_1 = 0 \quad ; \quad  m_1n_1/(q-r)+n_1l_1/(r-p)+l_1m_1/(p-q)=0 \\
 &l_2 + m_2 + n_2 = 0 \quad ; \quad  m_2n_2/(q-r)+n_2l_2/(r-p)+l_2m_2/(p-q)=0 \\
\end{aligned}

where $p,q,r$ are constants. Of course, we also know that

\begin{aligned}
 &l_1^2 + m_1^2 + n_1^2 = 1  \\
 &l_2^2 + m_2^2 + n_2^2 = 1  
\end{aligned}

From these 6 equations, we need to deduce that $l_1l_2 + m_1m_2 + n_1n_2 = \tfrac12$.

I was not successful in doing this. Brute force algebra is too laborious, and there is probably some clever shortcut that I'm not able to see.